# Using fzero to solve eqn in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I hope this is the right area. I'm trying to get this code to work in MatLab.

```
function y=test(x)
    y=-x+(B/(B-1))*(r-a)*p+(B/(B-1))*(r-a)*(b((1-(b/x)^(B-1))/r-  a)+p* ((b/x)^B))/(1-(b/x)^B);
end
```

I then jump to the command value and type this:

```
B=3.0515;
b=1.18632*10^5;
a=.017;
r=.054;
p=5931617;
```

I then try to find the zeros of the first equation by typing this and I get errors:

```
solution=fzero(@test,5000000)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error: File: test.m Line: 5 Column: 1    This statement is not
>   inside any function.    (It follows the END that terminates the
>   definition of the function        "test".)

New error

> Error using fzero (line 289)
>   FZERO cannot continue because user supplied function_handle ==> @(x)
>   (test(x,B,b,a,r,p))
>   failed with the error below.
>
> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please ***edit your question*** to include the verbatim error message that you received. ALWAYS include the exact error you get in your question. But also, if you are defining `B`, `b`, `a` etc in the commend line, they will not have scope in your function `test`. So as far as `test` is concerned they are essentially undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that this is a problem of [scoping](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Scope_(computer_science)), you are defining variables (`B`, `b`, etc...) in the command line but trying to use them inside your `test` function where they are out of scope. You should alter your test function to take these in as parameters and then use an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) so that your call to `test` in `fsolve` still only takes a single parameter:

```
function y=test(x, B, b, r, a, p)
    y=-x+(B/(B-1))*(r-a)*p+(B/(B-1))*(r-a)*(b((1-(b/x)^(B-1))/r-  a)+p* ((b/x)^B))/(1-(b/x)^B);
end
```

and

```
B=3.0515;
b=1.18632*10^5;
a=.017;
r=.054;
p=5931617;

solution=fzero(@(x)(test(x,B,b,a,r,p)),5000000)
```

As an aside, unless you really do mean matrix multiplication, I would suggest that you replace all your `*`s and `/`s in `test` with the element-wise operators `.*` and `./`. If you are dealing with scalars, it doesn't matter now, but it makes a big difference if you later want to scale your project and need a vectorized solution.

Regarding the errors you have added to your question:

1. You can't put code after the `end` in your function file. (With the exception of local functions). Your objective function should be an .m-file containing the code for one single function.
2. This is because in your test function you have `...b((1-(b/x)^(B-1))...` which in MATLAB means you are trying to index the variable `b` in which case the value of `(1-(b/x)^(B-1)` has to be a positive integer. I'm guess you are missing a `*`

Comment: Can you explain why I'm getting the error above in original post?

Comment: @MSanders the error is pretty clear, you have put code after the `end` of your function in your function file. In MATLAB you are not allowed to do that. Your `test` function should be the only code in it's own .m-file with the same name as the function.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Now getting this error                                                      `Error using fzero (line 289)
FZERO cannot continue because user supplied function_handle ==> @(x)(test(x,B,b,a,r,p))
failed with the error below.

 Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`

Comment: @MSanders This is because in your `test` function you have `...b((1-(b/x)^(B-1))...` which in MATLAB means you are trying to index the variable `b` in which case the value of `(1-(b/x)^(B-1)` has to be a positive integer. I'm guess you are missing a `*`

Comment: @MSanders no problem, if this has solved your problem then you should consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
function y=test(x)
    y=-x+(B/(B-1))*(r-a)*p+(B/(B-1))*(r-a)*(b((1-(b/x)^(B-1))/r-  a)+p* ((b/x)^B))/(1-(b/x)^B);
end
```

cannot access variables in your workspace. You need to pass the values in somehow. You could do something like:

```
function y=test(x,B,b,a,r,p)
    y=-x+(B/(B-1))*(r-a)*p+(B/(B-1))*(r-a)*(b((1-(b/x)^(B-1))/r-  a)+p* ((b/x)^B))/(1-(b/x)^B);
end
```

and then you can create an implicit wrapper function:

```
B=3.0515;
b=1.18632*10^5;
a=.017;
r=.054;
p=5931617;
solution = fzero(@(x) test(x,B,b,a,r,p),5000000)
```

I haven't tested whether fzero returns sensible results, but this code shouldn't give an error.

Comment: I run the code you all suggested and get the following error                           `Error: File: test.m Line: 5 Column: 1`
`This statement is not inside any function.`
 `(It follows the END that terminates the definition of the function "test".)`

Comment: You need to do some tutorials how to write functions in Matlab. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/programming-and-data-types.html

I'm guessing you have a function defined in a script file, and it needs to be in its own separate file.